# Extract max site number from web page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need ixtract max page number from [propertyes web site](https://www.nehnutelnosti.sk/vyhladavanie/). Screen: [image: number of site].
My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.nehnutelnosti.sk/vyhladavanie/'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id = 'inzeraty')

sitenums = soup.find_all('ul', class_='component-pagination__items d-flex align-items-center')
sitenums.find_all('li', class_='component-pagination__item')
```

My code returns error:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `css selector` and grab the second value from end.

Here's how:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

css = ".component-pagination .component-pagination__item a, .component-pagination .component-pagination__item span"
page = requests.get('https://www.nehnutelnosti.sk/vyhladavanie/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').select(css)[-2]
print(soup.getText(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
2309
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea but doing faster filtering within css selectors rather than indexing, using [nth-last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)

> The :nth-last-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their
> position among a group of siblings, counting from the end.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.nehnutelnosti.sk/vyhladavanie')
soup = bs(r.text, "lxml")
print(int(soup.select_one('.component-pagination__item:nth-last-child(2) a').text.strip()))
```